# Instruction Encoding?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, att, instruction-encoding

My professor wanted to show us how to decode instructions, as an example he took (at&t syntax):

```
movq $8, 4(%rdx,%rsi,4)
```

I'm quit lost on why he chose the opcode to be C7.

From an online table I found:

```
C7- move imm32 to r/m32 or imm32 (sign extended to 64 bits) to r/m64
```

How he figured out it's sign extended, plus why we are moving 32 imm? The instruction is so clear it's `movq` not `movl`

Comment: Please show the full encoding of the instruction. Often you need to decode (up to) several bytes in order to know which variant you have.

Comment: "or imm32 (sign extended to 64 bits) to r/m64" is the key here.  This applies if you have a REX prefix byte, which isn't considered part of the opcode. `8` can be encoded as a 32-bit number, but what's actually stored is the 64-bit number obtained by sign extension, so the `q` suffix is appropriate.

Comment: There is no other option except the sign extending `mov` because there is no `mov r/m64, imm64`.